# How to know which extensions is overriding Magento core checkout classes?

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

I am trying to find out which extension is overriding core classes of checkout.

Any help would be highly appreciated....
Thanks in advance..

Comment: Use "Developer path hint" to get an idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [this module](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/modules-conflict-detector.html) to see the rewrites in your Magento.

Answer (score 0):

Try [magerun](http://magerun.net/)

cd to your Magento folder and run `n98-magerun.phar dev:module:rewrite:list`

This will list all class rewrites, you should look for something like `*Model_Layer*`